# DJANGO 1.9 | views.py | execute *.bat file | location for save file

Tags: python, django, batch-file, django-views, batch-processing

I have 2 questions(I could not find answer on stackoverflow):

**First question:**

I added run_command.bat file to:

```
DjangoProj/
---DjangoApp/
------views.py
------run_command.bat
```

In method **save_logs** in **DjangoProj/DjangoApp/views.py** I tried:

```
def save_logs(request):
    choosenMachines = request.GET.getlist('mvsMachine')
    (data,errors) = subprocess.Popen(r'run_command.bat' + str(choosenMachines), shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

But I got this error:

> the run_command.bat is not recognize as external or internal command,
>   exec file or batch file

I suppose that Django is currently in another path(the question is which)

**And second question:**

Where is saved txt file created by method from **DjangoProj/DjangoApp/views.py**

```
def set_parameters_on_ftp(request):
    with open('start_task.txt', 'w') as f:
        for command in commands:
            f.write(command+'\n')
    return
```

It suppose it should be in: **DjangoProj/DjangoApp/***

Comment: No space after `.bat` in .Popen is intended? Try adding one.

Comment: This is not problem :) If I added space problem still occur. In my opinion reason is execution path for Django. It is different even if Django is in views.py so it isn't see *bat file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question:

```
import os

#Set myPath variable to the path of the file being executed
myPath =  os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

#Change current working directory to myPath
os.chdir(myPath)
#Or change current working directory to a subdirectory of myPath
os.chdir(os.path.join(myPath, 'subFolder'))
```

For the second question:

```
import os

#Check the current working directory. The txt file is getting saved here.
os.getcwd()

#This can be changed by changing the working directory as described in the answer to the first question.
```

EDIT: Changed the os.chdir() syntax error in the first part.

Comment: I found another way(using **static** folder) but thanks a lot. It will be helpful in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

Your guess was true.
Django current running path is not in your project folder.
In my testing it was in C:\Python27
you must give exact path or use PROJECT_ROOT variable in settings file.
Have fun

Comment: I found another way(using **static** folder) but thanks a lot. It will be helpful in the future :)